# Given R.V $X_i\geq0$ where $X_i$ is a sequence if $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X_n}]\to\infty$ then for sure the following doesn't hold $X_n\underset{a.s}{\to}0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Given R.V $X_i\geq0$ where $X_i$ is a sequence if $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X_n}]\to\infty$
> then for sure the following doesn't hold $X_n\underset{a.s}{\to}0$
> Prove or disprove

I think this is not true but I can't find the right sequence does'nt converge

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be any positive random variable with $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}]=\infty$ and define $X_n := X \cdot 1_{\{X \geq n\}}$, then
$$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X_n}] = \infty$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, although $X_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a counterexample:

Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathfrak{B}([0,1]),\lambda|_{[0,1]}$) and set $X_n=n^41_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$.
Then $E(\sqrt{X_n})=n$ but the sequence $(X_n)$ converges to the constant $0$ pointwise (so in aprticular almost surely).